# Why doesn't operator %in% work with tibbles?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I'm working with a tibble dataframe and I need to subset it, lefting only the lines which the variable "code" match the vector of chosen codes. Recently I'm entering the `dplyr` world, so I'm trying to use tibbles and `%>%` for it.

For example, let `code` and `df` be:

```
v_code <-c(314480505000001, 314480505000002, 314480505000003, 
          314480505000004, 314480505000005, 314480505000006, 
          314480505000007, 314480505000008, 314480505000009, 
          314480505000010)
code<-tibble(code=v_code)
v_df <- c(314470605000018, 314470605000019, 314470605000020, 
            314470605000021, 314470605000022, 314480505000001, 
            314480505000002, 314480505000003, 314480505000004, 
            314480505000005, 314480505000006, 314480505000007, 
            314480505000008, 314480505000009, 314480505000010)
df <- tibble (v_df, da = 1:15)
df2 <- data.frame(v_df, da = 1:15)
```

So, if I try:

```
df2[which(df2$v_df %in% v_code),]
```

I get what I want, but using tibbles:

```
df %>% filter(v_df %in% code)
```

I got

```
# A tibble: 0 x 2
# ... with 2 variables: v_df <dbl>, da <int>
```

In the same way, typing `which(tibble(v_df) %in% code)` returns `integer(0)`.

I tried convert `code` and `v_df` into characters, but I doesn't work either.

I would thank any help.

Comment: `filter(df, v_df %in% unlist(code))` works. Two things: (1) if `code` has multiple columns, it checks against all of them; (2) if all columns in `code` are not the same `class(.)`, then your comparison tests may be slightly different due to class-casting when concatenating different-class objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

v_code <-c(314480505000001, 314480505000002, 314480505000003, 
           314480505000004, 314480505000005, 314480505000006, 
           314480505000007, 314480505000008, 314480505000009, 
           314480505000010)
code<-tibble(code=v_code)
v_df <- c(314470605000018, 314470605000019, 314470605000020, 
          314470605000021, 314470605000022, 314480505000001, 
          314480505000002, 314480505000003, 314480505000004, 
          314480505000005, 314480505000006, 314480505000007, 
          314480505000008, 314480505000009, 314480505000010)
df <- tibble (v_df, da = 1:15)
df2 <- data.frame(v_df, da = 1:15)

df %>% filter(v_df %in% code$code)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
      v_df    da
     <dbl> <int>
 1 3.14e14     6
 2 3.14e14     7
 3 3.14e14     8
 4 3.14e14     9
 5 3.14e14    10
 6 3.14e14    11
 7 3.14e14    12
 8 3.14e14    13
 9 3.14e14    14
10 3.14e14    15
```

Comment: ok, but code$code isn't a tibble. So, the point is: do I always need a vector (not a tibble) after the operator %in%?

Comment: Yes of course. How would the operator %in% know which variable value it should compare? Unless the `code` variable is contained in `df`. However, then it would have to be the same length as the other variables in `df`.

Comment: %in% operator in R, is used to identify if an element belongs to a vector or Dataframe. If you write `df%>% filter (vdf% in% vscode)` this will also work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to address the question here, so hopefully it helps you understand how `%in%` works, and when and how it can be used.

The reason your example doesn't work is because `code` is a tibble. If `code` is a vector (`v_code`), then it will work. For example:

```
df %>% filter(v_df %in% v_code)

# # A tibble: 10 x 2
#      v_df    da
#     <dbl> <int>
# 1 3.14e14     6
# 2 3.14e14     7
# 3 3.14e14     8
# 4 3.14e14     9
# 5 3.14e14    10
# 6 3.14e14    11
# 7 3.14e14    12
# 8 3.14e14    13
# 9 3.14e14    14
# 10 3.14e14   15
```

See `` ?`%in%` `` for more details, but in short:

> x %in% table 
> x = vector or NULL: the values to be matched. Long vectors are supported 
> table = vector or NULL: the values to be matched against. Long vectors are not supported.

When filtering using `%in%`, in this example you are supplying a column as `x`, which is treated as a vector and then compared to the `table` vector you supply.

I guess this could be a little confusing seeing as you can supply a tibble column as the first argument, but the second argument has to be a vector. To make it more obvious why this wouldn't work, imagine if the `code` tibble had multiple columns - which column(s) would `%in%` use for it's comparison?

However, it looks like you both `x` and `table` can be columns, if they are in the same tibble. For example, let's make a tibble with 2 columns which we want to compare:

```
tibble(
  x = letters[1:10], 
  y = letters[c(1:5, 8:6, 9:10)]
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    match = x == y
  ) %>% 
  {. ->> my_tibb}

my_tibb

# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#    x     y     match
#    <chr> <chr> <lgl>
# 1  a     a     TRUE 
# 2  b     b     TRUE 
# 3  c     c     TRUE 
# 4  d     d     TRUE 
# 5  e     e     TRUE 
# 6  f     h     FALSE
# 7  g     g     TRUE 
# 8  h     f     FALSE
# 9  i     i     TRUE 
# 10 j     j     TRUE
```

Now, we use `%in%` to see if `x` matches `y`. Of course this could be done using `x == y` or `match == TRUE` for this example, but this demonstrates how it still works.

```
my_tibb %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  filter(
    x %in% y
  )

# # A tibble: 8 x 3
# # Rowwise: 
#   x     y     match
#   <chr> <chr> <lgl>
# 1 a     a     TRUE 
# 2 b     b     TRUE 
# 3 c     c     TRUE 
# 4 d     d     TRUE 
# 5 e     e     TRUE 
# 6 g     g     TRUE 
# 7 i     i     TRUE 
# 8 j     j     TRUE
```

Alternatively, if your `table` object was a column which itself contained a vector, then `%in%` can still be used. In this example, we make a column `z_list` which is a list of 6 random letters. This is coerced to a string (`z_string`) just so we can see which letters they are in the tibble console preview:

```
set.seed(3)

tibble(
  x = letters[1:10]
) %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(
    z_list = list(runif(6, min = 1, max = 26) %>%
               round %>%
               letters[.]),
    z_string = str_c(z_list, collapse = ', ')
  ) %>% 
  {. ->> my_tibb2}

my_tibb2

# # A tibble: 10 x 3
# # Rowwise: 
#    x     z_list    z_string        
#    <chr> <list>    <chr>           
# 1  a     <chr [6]> e, u, k, i, p, p
# 2  b     <chr [6]> d, h, o, q, n, n
# 3  c     <chr [6]> n, o, w, v, d, s
# 4  d     <chr [6]> w, h, g, a, d, c
# 5  e     <chr [6]> g, u, p, x, o, t
# 6  f     <chr [6]> j, j, e, l, g, i
# 7  g     <chr [6]> w, f, o, f, h, u
# 8  h     <chr [6]> e, o, k, h, b, d
# 9  i     <chr [6]> i, u, g, f, w, z
# 10 j     <chr [6]> v, x, m, g, d, h
```

Then we can use `%in%` to see when `x` is in the `z_list` column:

```
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
# # Rowwise: 
#   x     z_list    z_string        
#   <chr> <list>    <chr>           
# 1 d     <chr [6]> w, h, g, a, d, c
# 2 h     <chr [6]> e, o, k, h, b, d
# 3 i     <chr [6]> i, u, g, f, w, z
```

`x %in% z_string` doesn't work because `z_string` is a character string of several letters (like a word), so a single-letter string (`x`) won't match it.

If you did want to see if a letter (`x`) was in a word, you would have to split the word into separate letters using `str_extract_all()` and make it into a list, like below.

```
my_tibb2 %>%
  mutate(
    word = str_replace_all(z_string, ', ', ''), 
    word_list = str_extract_all(word, boundary('character'))
  ) %>% 
  {. ->> my_tibb3}

# # A tibble: 10 x 5
# # Rowwise: 
#     x     z_list    z_string         word   word_list
#     <chr> <list>    <chr>            <chr>  <list>   
#  1  a     <chr [6]> e, u, k, i, p, p eukipp <chr [6]>
#  2  b     <chr [6]> d, h, o, q, n, n dhoqnn <chr [6]>
#  3  c     <chr [6]> n, o, w, v, d, s nowvds <chr [6]>
#  4  d     <chr [6]> w, h, g, a, d, c whgadc <chr [6]>
#  5  e     <chr [6]> g, u, p, x, o, t gupxot <chr [6]>
#  6  f     <chr [6]> j, j, e, l, g, i jjelgi <chr [6]>
#  7  g     <chr [6]> w, f, o, f, h, u wfofhu <chr [6]>
#  8  h     <chr [6]> e, o, k, h, b, d eokhbd <chr [6]>
#  9  i     <chr [6]> i, u, g, f, w, z iugfwz <chr [6]>
# 10  j     <chr [6]> v, x, m, g, d, h vxmgdh <chr [6]>
```

Then, we can use `filter()` as we did before:

```
my_tibb3 %>% 
  filter(
    x %in% word_list
  )

# # A tibble: 3 x 5
# # Rowwise: 
#   x     z_list    z_string         word   word_list
#   <chr> <list>    <chr>            <chr>  <list>   
# 1 d     <chr [6]> w, h, g, a, d, c whgadc <chr [6]>
# 2 h     <chr [6]> e, o, k, h, b, d eokhbd <chr [6]>
# 3 i     <chr [6]> i, u, g, f, w, z iugfwz <chr [6]>
```